# C: Freeing a malloc'd array at the wrong time?

Tags: c, arrays, free

I have a `struct cell` ->

```
struct cell {
    double x, y, h, g, rhs;
    struct key *keys;
};
```

And I'm using the following method to free a cell ->

```
void cellFree(struct cell *c)   {
    // Free the keys
    free(c->keys);

    // Free the cell itself.
    free(c);
}

void cellFreeSors(struct cell *cn)  {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {
        // Free keys
        free(cn[i].keys);
    }
    // Free array
    free(cn);
}
```

Now, I'm facing a weird problem with one of the malloc'd arrays I've created.
Basically, I'm trying to find the neighbors of a cell and doing some processing based on their values using the following two methods ->

```
struct cell * cellGetSuccessors(struct cell *c, struct cell *sstart, struct cell *sgoal, double km) {
        int i;

        // CREATE 5 CELLS
        struct cell *cn = malloc(5 * sizeof (struct cell));
            if (cn == NULL) {
            printf("--> Unable to malloc *cn!\n");
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
            }

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)  {
            cn[i].keys = malloc(sizeof(struct key));
                if (cn[i].keys == NULL) {
                printf("--> Unable to malloc *cn[%d].keys!\n", i);
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return NULL;
            }
            cellCopyValues(&cn[i], c);
        }

        // MAKE THEM NEIGHBORS
        // PROCESS

        return cn;
    }


    double cellRHS(struct cell *c, struct cell *sstart, struct cell *sgoal, double km, struct cell * prevCell)  {
        // GET NEIGHBORS of c
        struct cell *cn = cellGetSuccessors(c, sstart, sgoal, km);
        double minsum;

        // SOME PROCESS TO UPDATE minsum
        minsum = 5.232111; // SAY

        // Free memory
        cellFreeSors(cn);

        return minsum;
    }
```

Trouble is, when I call `cellFreeSors()` in `cellRHS()`, I run into problems later..
This is how these functions are called..

```
struct cell *u = cellCreateNew();
u->rhs = cellRHS(u, sstart, sgoal, km, prevCell);
queueAdd(&U, u);
```

This gives me a segmentation error when I try to print my queue ->

```
    QUEUE CONTENTS
    ==================================================================
    F -> 0x2354550
    L - >0x2354550
    (1) [0x2354550] X 50.000000, Y 45.000000    PREV: (nil) NEXT: 0x4014000000000000
Segmentation fault
```

As you can see, the NEXT for the entry seems to be initialized for some reason.
The same code when executed WITHOUT `cellRHS()` works fine .. ->

```
struct cell *u = cellCreateNew();
queueAdd(&U, u);

    QUEUE CONTENTS
    ==================================================================
    F -> 0x2354550
    L - >0x2354550
    (1) [0x2354550] X 50.000000, Y 45.000000    PREV: (nil) NEXT: (nil)
```

Why is `cellFreeSors()` causing this problem? I've no use for the spawned neighbors of u beyond the scope of `cellRHS`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks..

** EDITS
The struct for queue_node is

```
/* QUEUE NODE
 * ----------------------------
 * Contains a struct cell c and
 * reference to next queue_node
 */
struct queue_node   {
    struct cell *c;
    struct queue_node *next;
    struct queue_node *prev;
};

/* PRIORITY QUEUE
 * ----------------------------
 * The queue itself, with first
 * and last pointers to queue_nodes
 */
struct priority_queue   {
    struct queue_node *first;
    struct queue_node *last;
};
```

The `queuePrint()` method shows queue contents ->

```
void queuePrint(struct priority_queue *q)
{
    printf("\n\n\tQUEUE CONTENTS\n\t==================================================================\n");
    int i = 1;
    struct queue_node *temp = q->first;
    printf("\tF -> %p\n\tL -> %p\n", q->first, q->last);
    while(temp != NULL) {
        printf("\t(%d) [%p]\tX %f, Y %f\tPREV: %p\tNEXT: %p", i, temp, temp->c->x, temp->c->y, temp->prev, temp->next);
        printf("\n");
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: No need to set `ENOMEM` yourself; `malloc` will do that for you. In fact, it may hide other errors. What does `cellCopyValues` do?

Comment: I don't see a prev or next pointer in your struct.  And you didn't include the code that is segfaulting (I'm guessing that's in queueAdd, or whatever is displaying the queue contents).

Comment: don't forget about larsmans question on `cellCopyValues`, plus he's spot on regarding `errno`, you shouldn't be changing it.

Comment: Do you init the `prev` and `next` pointers when you create the queue entry? The code to `queueAdd()` might help. But, when you create a new queue item, initialise it before adding it to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions here:

1. Use a centralized allocCell() and
   freeCell() method. This allows you
   to trace each allocated and
   deallocated cell exactly.
2. Put an id
   on each cell. Again, this allows
   detailed tracing. You can compile it
   one way for production and another
   for debug if space is an issue.
3. Write tracing routines for the cell,
   to see that your routines are only
   freeing allocated cells, that any
   cell is only freed once, etc. You
   could even write a hashtable to
   store the id's of allocated and
   freed cells (of course just during
   debug) and write verification
   checks.
4. You are probably going to
   run into memory errors again if you
   don't do this.
5. Even if you do this, you will run into memory errors again, but these tools will help you track it down faster next time.
6. Switch to C# or java and don't free anything :)